# How do I get VAT rates out of QuickBooks

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I can use the SalesTaxCodeQuery in the SDK to get a list of the different tax codes that are configured in Quickbooks.
But I need to determine the actual % VAT Rate that applies to these tax codes.
What query do I need to use to get that information out of Quickbooks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, QuickBooks does not support returning this information to you.

Comment: Keith ... Many thanks!  That saved me an awful lot of searching through API specs. :-)